# Passing Parameter to next form starting with parameter input dialog

Tags: ms-access, parameters, vba, openargs

I'm trying to create a database that is user friendly. So far I've developed two forms. 
*Form 1 shows an overview of orders. Form 2 shows the details of a specific order.* Form 2 is build on a query that retrieves information from different tables.

When I open form 2, a parameter input dialog box appears asking me which ordernr he has to look for. When I type in a number, the specific details from that record are shown.

Now comes the tricky part. form 1 shows the overview. When i click on an ordernr a textbox is filled. I did this to confirm the program reads the right number.

My question: How do I get the number from my textfield in form 1, into the parameter input dialog in form 2? The numbers are stored as text so no conversion is needed.

I saw a lot of solutions with **DoCmd.OpenForm "Formname" ,,,,,, OpenArgs**. I do believe this can be the sollution. I just don't know how to get OpenArgs into the Parameter Input Dialog.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Why do you want to use OpenArgs rather than Where? Is the code running on form1? If so, just use `Me.NameOfFieldOrControl`, if the record has focus, you do not need a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Change the query of the second form to have the value of the text box that you populate as a filter on the ordernr field.  You might also to set the 'Modal' property of the second form to 'True' as this will prevent (or hinder at least) unsynced forms.